# Basic Xcode - reference in random number generator not working

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a very basic (I think) program in Xcode.  I am trying to write an app for "drawing straws" where the last person who is chosen is the loser.  There are a few things I'd like to do.  First, see the code below:

```
import UIKit

let players = 4

var playerNames: [String] = ["John", "Tyler", "Pete", "Dave"]

var draw = Int(arc4random_uniform(4))

playerNames.removeAtIndex(draw)

print(playerNames)

let round2 = playerNames.count

var draw2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))

playerNames.removeAtIndex(draw2)

print(playerNames)

let round3 = playerNames.count

var draw3 = Int(arc4random_uniform(1))

playerNames.removeAtIndex(draw3)

print(playerNames)
```

The first thing that's wrong is I'm currently hard-coding the random integer being drawn in `var draw = Int(arc4random_uniform(4))`. When I try to reference `players` instead of just typing in `4`, I get an error. Can someone please help explain the problem there?

I'll stop there for now to see if I can fix that, and I'll wait until that is fixed before posting a new question.  Thank you.

Comment: Show the code that actually causes the error as well as your code which doesn't...

Comment: Are you saying that the following `var draw = Int(arc4random_uniform(player));` cause an error?  If so, what is that error?

Answer (score 2):

The function [arc4random_uniform()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html) takes a UInt32, so you need to declare the variable players as UInt32

```
let players: UInt32 = 4

var draw = (arc4random_uniform(players))
```

For handling the round variables, you would cast the count to UInt32.

```
let round2 = UInt32(playerNames.count)
```

You can also refactor your code

```
let players: UInt32 = 4

var playerNames: [String] = ["John", "Tyler", "Pete", "Dave"]
println(playerNames)

for loop in 1...players {
    RemovePlayer(&playerNames)
    println(playerNames)
}
```

And the code for the `RemovePlayer` function

```
func RemovePlayer(inout names: [String]) {
    // get the number of names in the array
    var maxNames = UInt32(names.count)
    var draw = Int((arc4random_uniform(maxNames)))

    names.removeAtIndex(draw)
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that works perfectly.  Follow up (I could put this in a new question if that is more appropriate), what about when I move further down for an additional draw (like in `draw2`)? Because now I'm pulling in the `count` from `playernames`, but `playernames` is a string and not UInt32.  Is there a way to reconcile that?  Thank you.

Comment: Instead of declaring your player var UInt32 you should just change your random method to var draw = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(player)))

Comment: var draw = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(playerNames.count)))

Comment: I'd suggest discarding  `players` entirely, and just use `playerNames.count`.  That avoids hardwiring your code to a particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As Blackfrog already stated your randomization function requires a `UInt32`

Since you stated that you just started programing I would like to give you some other advice. Your code can be written as:

```
var playerNames = ["John", "Tyler", "Pete", "Dave"]

for var index = playerNames.count ; index > 1 ; index -= 1{
    var random:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(index)))
    playerNames.removeAtIndex(random)
}

println(playerNames[0])
```

This has a few advantages. At the moment you are hardcoding the values for how many players join a game. You will need to re-write an unnecessary amount of code if you want to add a player.

Let’s see what the above code does:

We start by declaring the `playerNames` adding a type declaration of `[String]` isn’t necessary, swift already knows that it is this type by its initial value.

```
for var index = playerNames.count; index > 1 ; index -= 1{
```

We create a new variable called `index` this will be set to the amount of items in the `playerNames` array (4 in this case)
After this we will declare that we want the loop as long as our `index` is greater than `1` this will make it run 3 times and make sure we are left with 1 item in our array
The `index -=1` will subtract `1` from the `index` after each iteration through the loop.

```
var random:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(index)))
```

Here we declare a new variable `random` this will be of type Integer. Let’s work from the inside to the outside. `UIt32(index)` will convert our `index` which is of type `Int` to a type of `UInt32`, this is needed cause our random function requires a `UInt32`
Next up we request a random value which will lay between the `index` and `0` (thus between the bounds of the array). We want to remove the player who belongs to this random value in our array. To do this we need to convert our random `Uint32` back to an `Int` we can do this by using `Int()`.

Next we remove the player at the `index` using

```
playerNames.removeAtIndex(random)
```

Lastly we print the first (and only) item left in the array using

```
println(playerNames[0])
```